# setInterval Not running inside click() function

Tags: javascript, facebook, setinterval

This question has not been asked before as I have searched quite extensively for an answer and I am hitting a brick wall.

When I run this code through the console or outisde an onclick function it works perfectly by opening a facebook oauth dialog and when it is finished it closes and the original page reloads.

```
var win = window.open('/auth/facebook','location=yes, scrollbars=yes, width=640, height=359', true);


var intervalID = setInterval(function(){
      if(win.closed){
          location.reload();
      }
 }, 100);
```

My problem is that within a click() function it doesn't work at all.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        var intervalID = null;
        var win = null

        $("#flogin").click(function(){

            win = window.open('/auth/facebook','location=yes, scrollbars=yes, width=640, height=359', true);


            intervalID = setInterval(function(){
                    if(win.closed){
                        location.reload();
                    }

                }, 100);
        });
    });
```

This may seem like a really simple question to all of you and there may be a simple answer but I cannot seem to find. Thanks for your help!

Comment: What about the line `var win = window.open`.., if you already have `var win = null` declared in the start, you should just have `win = window.open`..

Comment: The html is very simple:

<a href="" id="flogin">Sign in</a>

And I removed the vars with no result

Comment: @chapmatic I have answer you question

Comment: Btw, an empty href is the same as the current location :) if you want to stay on the page you should at least use `"#"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as you mentioned on your comment you are using `<a> tag` 
use `preventDefault` to prevent the default action

this should work

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var intervalID = null;
    var win = null

    $("#flogin").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault(); //prevents the default action
        win = window.open('/auth/facebook','location=yes, scrollbars=yes, width=640, height=359', true);


        intervalID = setInterval(function(){
                if(win.closed){
                    location.reload();
                }

            }, 100);
    });
});
```